# Kohana auth login fails every time

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-auth

I'm quite new to Auth module, and i'm trying to get login working, after reading documentation and googling like crazy i have this simple piece of code...

```
    Auth::instance()->login('test', 'test');
if (Auth::instance()->logged_in()){
   $this->request->redirect('user/index/');
}else{
   echo 'fail';
}
```

This always returns false, my registration script looks like this:

```
$model = ORM::factory('user');
$model->values(array(
       'username' => 'admin',
       'email' => 'adsmin@example.com',
       'password' => 'test',
       'password_confirm' => 'test',
    ));
$model->save();
```

It creates user just fine, also it sets `role_id` to 1 and 2 which means i have admins/login rights, but it keeps failing anyways, if i would use `Auth::instance()->force_login($user);` everything work's just fine, so i'm guessing problem could be with hashing, but i have no idea where.

Comment: May be `Auth::instance()->login('admin', 'test');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set driver to 'orm' in `config/auth.php`

Comment: did already it's not the problem, anyways for now i solved problem by deleting 

`if (isset($this->_users[$username]) AND $this->_users[$username] === $password)` from `\modules\auth\classes\kohana\auth`

Answer (score 0):

Did you store the plaintext password or the hashed password? I think the Auth module login function hashes the password. So maybe you should save the hashed password.

You could hash your password by using:

```
Auth::instance()->hash('your_password');
```